# Raise section name with titlesec

Tags: titlesec

I would like to raise the section title in the following piece of code when I used `titlesec` to produce the boxed section number, and have at the same height as the section number:

[image]

This is the MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{titlesec,tikz}

\titleformat{\section}
  {\bfseries}
  {    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[
      text width=1cm,
      minimum height=1cm,
      fill=red, 
      font=\color{white}\fontsize{20}{9}\sffamily,
      align=center
      ] (num) {\thesection};
    \end{tikzpicture}}
  {12pt}
{\normalfont\LARGE\bfseries\scshape\color{red}}


\begin{document}

\setcounter{chapter}{1} % just to emulate a chapter has started

\section{One two three}

\end{document}
```